# How can I show the groups label in lineplot.CI

Tags: r

I am trying to use the lineplot.CI command, but it doesnt indicate which line/dot represent which group in group factor. And it was working before, does anyone have any clue about that?
Or if I have to put anymore command.

as example, I am just using the following line:

```
lineplot.CI(x.factor,response,group,ylab,main="profile", data)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I think that I found what happened.
Just changed computers to one with a bigger screen, probably the label that would describe the group factor was too long, so it disappeared. :/